# Django pass template variable to custom templatetag

Tags: python, django, templates

I'd like to display django my error messages inside the form as a placeholder, instead of above the form input box itself. Is this possible in Django, or would I have to achieve this by writing some Javascript?

```
    <div class="form-group">

        {% if login_form.password.errors %}
            {% for error in login_form.password.errors %}
                <p>{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
            {{ login_form.password | placeholder:"password" | addClass:"form-control" }}
        </div>

    </div>
```

Specific lines of interest. I'd like to change this:

```
{{ login_form.password | placeholder:"password" | addClass:"form-control" }}
```

To this

```
{{ login_form.password | placeholder:{{ error }} | addClass:"form-control" }}
```

where {{error}} is an the Django error message thrown by the form

I'm thinking there must be some way of getting the string value of a template variable, but can't find any answers

EDIT: I've tried the following, to no avail

```
<div class="form-group">
    {% if login_form.password.errors %}
        {% for error in login_form.password.errors %}
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                {{ login_form.password | placeholder:{{ error|escape }} | addClass:"form-control" }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

My custom templatetag looks as follows

```
@register.filter(name='placeholder')
def placeholder(value, token):
    value.field.widget.attrs["placeholder"] = token
    return value
```

Django throws a TemplateSyntax Error complaining that:

placeholder requires 2 arguments, 1 provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the nested expression in django template system is incorrect, so `placeholder`'s filter argument shouldn't be enclosed in double brackets, but written directly:

```
{{ login_form.password | placeholder:error | addClass:"form-control" }}
```

Here, `error` variable is correctly evaluated in context of outer curly brackets scope.

Second, I'd suggest make sure about filter argument's type. If you do expect string value, you may use built-in filter to make an explicit conversion:

```
{% with err_msg=error|stringformat:"s" %}
{{ login_form.password | placeholder:err_msg | addClass:"form-control" }}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.

```
{{ login_form.password.errors }}
```

Here's the relevant documentation for that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

The piece of code should be re-written as

```
{{ login_form.password | placeholder:"password" | addClass:"form-control" }}
{% if login_form.password.errors %}
   <span class="error">{{ login_form.password.errors }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

or can be done in this way too

```
{{ login_form.password | placeholder:"password" | addClass:"form-control" }}
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="
{% if login_form.password.errors %}
   {{ login_form.password.errors }}
{% else %}
   password
{% endif %}
">
```

Comment: `{{ login_form.password | placeholder:{{ error|escape }} | addClass:"form-control" }}` Throws an error

Comment: Try the updated one. I don't think there's a non hacked way to it. Having a template tag inside another will be seen as a syntax error by django (`{{ error|escape }} ` )

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested yet, but this may work:

```
# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    class meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        error_messages = self.fields['myfield'].error_messages
        self.fields['myfield'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': error_messages})
```